# pass python argument to awk script

Tags: python, awk, arguments

I am using a python script which takes in few arguments:

```
 pipeline.py -t reg.bed -n WT -s run -ID 567
```

Inside the python script, i am using awk script which should take in the arguments passed above:

For instance, it should take the argument by name, ID = 567 and print it in a file:

```
awk '{print "567", $0}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Could anyone help me, how i can pass the string "567" to the awk command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do the job using python, then why to go for awk??

Answer (score 1):

use awk's `-v` option

```
awk -v id=567 '{print id, $0}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Although this awk script is so simple, surely you should implement it in python.

Comment: thanks!! But, i would not specify the value for id in the awk script. The value is passed as an argument to python script, which has to be parsed through awk.

Comment: Then you'll need to learn about how python handles command line arguments.

Answer (score -2):

Special attention should be paid to the **cmd format** inside `os.system`(quote shell cmd in python script).

I'll give an example to illustrate

---

I have a file named `bNormal1.bedgraph`. 
I want to extract the lines that satisfy my condition:

```
(NR==1 && $1== "track")||($1=="chr1" && $2>220138080  && $3 < 220138189)
```

And I want to use variables replacing some arguments:

```
chrom="chr1" $2=220138080 $3= 220138189
```

This is the right python cmd:

```
import os

chrom="chr1"

start=220138080

end=220138189

bedgraphfile="bNormal1.bedgraph"

os.system('awk  \'(NR==1 && $1== "track")||($1=="%s" && $2> %d && $3 < %d) {{print $0}} \' %s'%(chrom,start,end,bedgraphfile))**
```

**cmd output:**

```
track type=bedGraph name=bNormal1 visibility=full color=54,54,54

chr1    220138087   220138187   0.226285

0
```

---

Full content of the query file `bNormal1.bedgraph`:

```
track type=bedGraph name=bNormal1 visibility=full color=54,54,54


chr1    220138087   220138187   0.226285


chr1    220138229   220138314   0.226285
```